# Create objects while running in Unityscript (Unity)

Tags: object, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a task that I am supposed to create a web based client that allows users to create objects (in my case, furniture) and move them around and so on.

For this, I have created a button. When the button is pressed, I want to create an object, for example, a chair. For educational purposes, a cube works equally well.

The code I have to accomplish this is as following:

```
    function OnGUI() {

        if(GUI.Button(Rect(Screen.width - 170, Screen.height - Screen.height * 0.98,150,30), string)){

            GUI.Button(Rect(50,50,150,30), "test");

        }
    }
```

Here, I tried to create a new button, but the goal is to create an object of some sort.

I do not know how to proceed, and I have very little experience in Javascript.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are running 
based on [Unity Documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) for creating objects the correct function need to be called is Instantiate.
to do that you need to have a reference of an object you want to create.
Example:

```
    // Instantiates 10 copies of prefab each 2 units apart from each other
var prefab : Transform;//From the inspector drag and drop a prefab object(of any type) on the prefab slot
function Start ()
   {
       for (var i : int = 0;i < 10; i++) 
       {
           Instantiate (prefab, Vector3(i * 2.0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
       }
   }
```

According to this, your code could be modified as follows:

```
var prefab : Transform;//From the inspector drag and drop a prefab object(of any type) 
  function OnGUI() {

        if(GUI.Button(Rect(Screen.width - 170, Screen.height - Screen.height * 0.98,150,30), string))
        {
             var aPosition = Vector3(1, 1, 1);//Sets the position in the 3d space we are gonna position the prefab
             Instantiate (prefab, aPosition, Quaternion.identity);

        }
    }
```

Comment: That seemed to work just fine. However, if I want to create a new button (like a menu) when the button is clicked, the instantiate function does not work. Any ideas on how I could achieve that? That is, when the button is pressed, a selectionGrid of buttons is shown...

Comment: The problem here is that the Instantiate function cannot be used to create GUI.Elements, it requires an object as a parameter. According to your code, as long as you press the first GUI.Button another button of name test will be spawned